# Getting an error messsage when running sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I am getting this whenever I try to update and upgrade:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease              
Hit:4 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal InRelease  
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease             
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease            
Hit:7 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease               
Hit:8 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-security InRelease    
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
Hit:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy InRelease     
Hit:11 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-updates InRelease    
Hit:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:13 https://hub-dist.unity3d.com/artifactory/hub-debian-prod-local stable InRelease
Hit:14 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
W: https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu/dists/stable-focal/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/repos/deb/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  vlc-plugin-qt libvlc5 python2.7-minimal vlc-data libvlccore9 vlc imagemagick
  vlc-bin libjs-jquery-ui vlc-l10n libopenexr25 libpostproc55
  libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra vlc-plugin-samba libavcodec58
  libmagickwand-6.q16-6 vlc-plugin-notify libavutil56 imagemagick-6.q16
  libswscale5 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 vlc-plugin-access-extra vlc-plugin-skins2
  vlc-plugin-video-splitter libswresample3 imagemagick-6-common
  vlc-plugin-video-output libavformat58 python2.7 libpython2.7-minimal
  libvlc-bin libpython2.7-stdlib vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-visualization
  libavfilter7
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following packages have been kept back:
  gnome-remote-desktop
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
32 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up cups (2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.4) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by anothe
r process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package cups (--configure):
 installed cups package post-installation script subprocess returned error ex
it status 1
Setting up cups-bsd (2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.4) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by anothe
r process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package cups-bsd (--configure):
 installed cups-bsd package post-installation script subprocess returned erro
r exit status 1
Setting up grub-pc (2.06-2ubuntu7.2) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by anothe
r process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error
 exit status 1
Setting up libreoffice-common (4:7.5.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~lo1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by anothe
r process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-common (--configure):
 installed libreoffice-common package post-installation script subprocess ret
urned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport repor
t written because MaxReports is reached already
                                               dpkg: dependency problems prev
ent configuration of libreoffice-gnome:
 libreoffice-gnome depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~); however
:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-impress:
 libreoffice-impress depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~); howev
er:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-impress (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up gdm3 (42.0-1ubuntu7.22.04.3) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              debconf: DbDriv
er "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Reso
urce temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package gdm3 (--configure):
 installed gdm3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error ex
it status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependenc
y problems prevent configuration of python3-uno:
 python3-uno depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~); however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-uno (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependenc
y problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-script-provider-bsh:
 libreoffice-script-provider-bsh depends on libreoffice-common; however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-script-provider-bsh (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up libp
am-cap:amd64 (1:2.44-1ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by anothe
r process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libpam-cap:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libpam-cap:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess retur
ned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependenc
y problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-core:
 libreoffice-core depends on libreoffice-common (>> 4:7.5.4~rc2); however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: error pro
cessing package libreoffice-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up sysstat (12.5.2-2ubuntu0.2) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by anothe
r process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package sysstat (--configure):
 installed sysstat package post-installation script subprocess returned error
 exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependenc
y problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-script-provider-js:
 libreoffice-script-provider-js depends on libreoffice-common; however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-script-provider-js depends on libreoffice-core-nogui | libreoffi
ce-core; however:
  Package libreoffice-core-nogui is not installed.
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-script-provider-js (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependenc
y problems prevent configuration of libreoffice:
 libreoffice depends on libreoffice-core (= 4:7.5.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~lo1)
; however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
 libreoffice depends on libreoffice-impress; however:
  Package libreoffice-impress is not configured yet.
 libreoffice depends on python3-uno; however:
  Package python3-uno is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependenc
y problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-calc:
 libreoffice-calc depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~); however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-calc depends on libreoffice-core (= 4:7.5.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
~lo1); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-calc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-base:
 libreoffice-base depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~); however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-base depends on libreoffice-core (= 4:7.5.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
~lo1); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport repor
t written because MaxReports is reached already
                                               dpkg: error processing package
 libreoffice-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-math:
 libreoffice-math depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~); however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-math depends on libreoffice-core (= 4:7.5.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
~lo1); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-math (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependenc
y problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-gtk3:
 libreoffice-gtk3 depends on libreoffice-core (= 4:7.5.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
~lo1); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-gtk3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-sdbc-postgresq
l:
 libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha)
; however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql depends on libreoffice-core-nogui | libreoffice-
core; however:
  Package libreoffice-core-nogui is not installed.
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport repor
t written because MaxReports is reached already
                                               dpkg: error processing package
 libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb:
 libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb depends on libreoffice-core-nogui | libreoffice-core
; however:
  Package libreoffice-core-nogui is not installed.
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependenc
y problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-writer:
 libreoffice-writer depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~); howeve
r:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-writer depends on libreoffice-core (= 4:7.5.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.22.04
.1~lo1); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-writer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependenc
y problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-report-builder:
 libreoffice-report-builder depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha);
 however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-report-builder depends on libreoffice-core | libreoffice-core-no
gui; however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
  Package libreoffice-core-nogui is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-report-builder (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependenc
y problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-draw:
 libreoffice-draw depends on libreoffice-common (>= 1:7.0.0~alpha~); however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-draw depends on libreoffice-core (= 4:7.5.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
~lo1); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-draw (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-java-common:
 libreoffice-java-common depends on libreoffice-common; however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-java-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport repor
t written because MaxReports is reached already
                                               dpkg: dependency problems prev
ent configuration of libreoffice-base-drivers:
 libreoffice-base-drivers depends on libreoffice-core-nogui | libreoffice-cor
e; however:
  Package libreoffice-core-nogui is not installed.
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-base-drivers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependenc
y problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-wiki-publisher:
 libreoffice-wiki-publisher depends on libreoffice-core; however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-wiki-publisher depends on libreoffice-java-common; however:
  Package libreoffice-java-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-wiki-publisher (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependenc
y problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-script-provider-python:
 libreoffice-script-provider-python depends on libreoffice-common; however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-script-provider-python depends on libreoffice-core-nogui | libre
office-core; however:
  Package libreoffice-core-nogui is not installed.
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-script-provider-python depends on python3-uno; however:
  Package python3-uno is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-script-provider-python (--configur
e):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependenc
y problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-nlpsolver:
 libreoffice-nlpsolver depends on libreoffice-calc; however:
  Package libreoffice-calc is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-nlpsolver depends on libreoffice-core; however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-nlpsolver depends on libreoffice-java-common; however:
  Package libreoffice-java-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-nlpsolver (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependenc
y problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-report-builder-bin:
 libreoffice-report-builder-bin depends on libreoffice-base; however:
  Package libreoffice-base is not configured yet.
 libreoffice-report-builder-bin depends on libreoffice-core; however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-report-builder-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependenc
y problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-sdbc-firebird:
 libreoffice-sdbc-firebird depends on libreoffice-core-nogui | libreoffice-co
re; however:
  Package libreoffice-core-nogui is not installed.
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-sdbc-firebird (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependenc
y problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-sdbc-mysql:
 libreoffice-sdbc-mysql depends on libreoffice-core-nogui | libreoffice-core;
 however:
  Package libreoffice-core-nogui is not installed.
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-sdbc-mysql (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependenc
y problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-base-core:
 libreoffice-base-core depends on libreoffice-core (= 4:7.5.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.22
.04.1~lo1) | libreoffice-core-nogui (= 4:7.5.4~rc2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~lo1); how
ever:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
  Package libreoffice-core-nogui is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-base-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were enc
ountered while processing:
 cups
 cups-bsd
 grub-pc
 libreoffice-common
 libreoffice-gnome
 libreoffice-impress
 gdm3
 python3-uno
 libreoffice-script-provider-bsh
 libpam-cap:amd64
 libreoffice-core
 sysstat
 libreoffice-script-provider-js
 libreoffice
 libreoffice-calc
 libreoffice-base
 libreoffice-math
 libreoffice-gtk3
 libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql
 libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb
 libreoffice-writer
 libreoffice-report-builder
 libreoffice-draw
 libreoffice-java-common
 libreoffice-base-drivers
 libreoffice-wiki-publisher
 libreoffice-script-provider-python
 libreoffice-nlpsolver
 libreoffice-report-builder-bin
 libreoffice-sdbc-firebird
 libreoffice-sdbc-mysql
 libreoffice-base-core
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Sorry for the long post. Just not too sure what to do here. Thanks in advanced to your assistance

Comment: " ...locked by another process" means there is another update or install process running. Reboot and try again.

Comment: I've rebooted many times and it still gives the same issue. If I remove Libre Office that part of the list goes away, but comes back when I reinstall it.

Comment: Yes it did!! thank you so much!